# Closing file handle causes troubles in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io

I have the following code for loading contents of the file and parse it with aeson into an object:

```
  loadFromFile filename = do
    fileHandle <- openFile ( dataDir ++ "/" ++ filename ) ReadMode
    contents <- B.hGetContents fileHandle
    let result = fromMaybe initial $! JSON.decode contents in do
      hClose fileHandle
      return $! result
```

The problem with this code is that it causes following errors:

```
filename.json: hGetBufSome: illegal operation (handle is closed)
filename.json: hGetBufSome: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

I do not quite understand why it thinks file handle is closed. I am reading it before closing the handle after all. Or is lazy evaluation affecting the order of execution? I tried adding corresponding `$!` operators to make it evaluate sooner, but it does not help. If I remove `hClose fileHandle` line, then I start getting sporadic errors of the following kind:

```
filename.json: openFile: resource busy (file is locked)
```

If somebody knows how to fix this catch22, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: `hGetContents` puts the handle in a semi-closed state, and uses the controversial "lazy IO". This means that the file is not read at that point, but will be read when `contents` is actually demanded, provided the file has not been closed. Lazy IO is notoriously hard to control, and will cause the errors you report. Maybe try to `evaluate result` before you close the handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of forcing the result after closing the handle, you should force the result before closing the handle, here's how you can do that with `BangPatterns`:

```hs
  loadFromFile filename = do
    fileHandle <- openFile ( dataDir ++ "/" ++ filename ) ReadMode
    contents <- B.hGetContents fileHandle
    let !result = fromMaybe initial $! JSON.decode contents
    hClose fileHandle
    return result
```

In this case a deepseq is not required, because (I believe) the `decode` function will process the whole input before deciding whether to return `Nothing` or `Just ...`, so forcing only that one level is enough.

And, if possible, it is better to avoid handles entirely:

```hs
  loadFromFile filename = do
    contents <- B.readFile ( dataDir ++ "/" ++ filename )
    return $! fromMaybe initial $! JSON.decode contents
```